# Detect Moto 360/circlular shape and onApplyWindowInsetListener not being called

Tags: android, wear-os, moto-360

It looks like common ways to detect the screen shape of the Moto 360 do not work properly.

I know there are reports saying that `windowInset.isRound()` returns false in the Moto 360.

Currently my code is the following

```
WatchViewStub viewStub = new WatchViewStub(this);
viewStub.setRoundLayout(com.pizzaentertainment.weatherwatchface.R.layout.bau);
viewStub.setRectLayout(com.pizzaentertainment.weatherwatchface.R.layout.bau_rect);
viewStub.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener( new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
    @Override
    public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsets windowInsets) {
        Log.d("ISWHAT?", "ASD" +windowInsets.isRound());
        return windowInsets;
    }
});
addContentView(viewStub, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
viewStub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub watchViewStub) {
        Log.d("INFLATED", "INFLATED");
    }
});
```

My main problem is that the `onApplyWindowInsets` never gets called on both my LG G watch and the Samsung Galaxy Gear Live. I made a test with a 360 user and, according to the test, that method doesn't get called on his device either.

1. Why is `OnApplyWindowInsetListener` not being called?
2. Why do people who got the callback working report that `windowInset.isRound()` returns false on the Moto 360?
3. How are we supposed to recognize the Moto 360 (and future ones with the circular shape)? From the `Build.MODEL`?

Answer (score 3):

I found too that setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener is not called on the real devices. It is checked on LG G Watch and Gear Live. Looks this is true for Moto 360 as well. I did the following workaround:

```
    WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLayoutInflated()");
            m_pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_square);
            m_roundScreen = false;
            if (m_pager == null) {
                m_pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_round);
                m_roundScreen = true;
            }
            // ... do other pager initializations
        }
    });
```

Set in your round and square layouts different ID for one of the components and check which one is loaded because I didn't find any other way. In the example I set for my GridViewPager pager_square in the square layout and pager_round in the round layout. Not very pretty but works well as a workaround.

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work? If GridViewStub loads the correct round or square layout it will work because I use it that way and on square screen it loads the square layout. I can't test what layout it loads on Moto 360 so does your statement means it doesn't load the correct layout?

Comment: Exactly... Moto 360 does not load the correct layout.

Comment: My Moto 360 loads the correct layout (round).
Software version:  `4.4W.1`
Build: `KGW42R`

Comment: This is how I did it for my app as well.  Simple work around if you need to know in the code which form factor the watch is.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be having this problem still, but I noticed that my round layout was not being inflated on my Moto 360. Instead my rectangular one was. I fixed this by changing the theme in the manifest file to `DeviceDefault`.